# objective c programmatically deallocate/release objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm working on an iPhone game and currently the game uses many `UIImageViews` to show space ships, bullets and other things. The game probably has 30-40 different subviews in the view controller and I've decided that I should probably programmatically add subviews when they are needed rather than starting the game with them in the hidden state and making them unhidden when needed (for performance issues) so here are my questions:

(1) will there be a significant performance gain from adding subviews when needed?

(2) how do I release a subview when ARC is enabled? Im trying to add the views (based on type) into an `NSMutableArray` when its created to hold it, and removing it from the array when I'm done using it, does removing it from the array deallocate that memory?

heres the code (theres an `NSTimer` that runs the movement method every 0.03 seconds, and the get and set methods are on an "instance variable" `NSMutableArray`);

```
-(void)movement {
    if (shootButton3.isHighlighted) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [self getBulletArray];
        [self setarray:array];
    }
    [self shootBullet: [self getArray]];
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getBulletArray {
    UIImageView *bullet = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(ship.center.x + 20, ship.center.y, 15, 3)];
    bullet.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bullet2.png"];
    bullet.hidden = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:bullet];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:bullet];
    return array;
}
-(void)shootBullet: (NSMutableArray *)bulletArray {

    for (int i = 0; i < [bulletArray count]; i++) {
        UIImageView *bullet = [bulletArray firstObject];
        bullet.center = CGPointMake(bullet.center.x + 4, bullet.center.y);
        if (bullet.center.x > 500) {
            bullet.hidden = YES;
            [bulletArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }

    }
}
-(void)setarray:(NSMutableArray *) array {
    bulletArray = array;
}
-(NSMutableArray *)getArray {
    return bulletArray;
}
```

Comment: "how do I release a subview when ARC is enabled?"  Remove it from the superview and nil any other pointers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

Question 1: Yes, there will be a performance increase for sure, regardless of how large the UIImageViews are.

Question 2: Simply set the imageView to nil: `self.imageView = nil;`

Comment: Make sure you also call `-removeFromSuperview` on the view to actually take it out of the view hierarchy.

Comment: I see, thank you for the tip, so first I set it to nil, then remove it from the view hierarchy? or vice versa?

Comment: I'd set it to nil first, then remove from the heirarchy.

Comment: @troop231 You can't set it to nil then remove it from the heirarchy... you'd be passing the `removeFromSuperView` message to `nil`...

Comment: I guess there's no reason to remove it from the heirarchy if he's going to reuse the property later when he goes and recreates the images.

Comment: hm... ok and setting it to nil will remove it whenever the "garbage collector" sees fit? (I learned java first, so I relate stuff to it sometimes to understand better)

Comment: quick question, setting the view to nil will allocate that memory, but I'm testing it and it's not disappearing.. how can I know that the bullet's memory has been allocated if it's still there?

Comment: ARC garbage collection is based on reference counting not mark-sweep or other periodic method, so once an object has no references it will be collected.